# localStorage element not updating after header

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, local-storage

I'm currently developing a personal project of a japanese language learning website. The user's progress is stored inside a localStorage variable. The problem I faced is that after setting the variable's value and placing the header to a different page, the localStorage variable doesn't update. If the header is removed it works fine. Any help would be very much appreciated. Please follow a snippet of my code. Thank you!

```
if (!in_array($id, $_SESSION['seenRight'])) {
    array_push($_SESSION['seenRight'],$id);
    if (count($_SESSION['seenRight']) == 10) {
        ?> <script> 
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                    <?php
                    // Check if there was already a localstorage for that level, make a percentage with the new added value, replace value.
                    // Lock the level.
                        if(count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) == 0) {
                            ?> localStorage.setItem("progressLevel" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['level'] ?>", "50");<?php
                        }
                        if(count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) > 0 && count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) <= 2) {
                            ?> localStorage.setItem("progressLevel" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['level'] ?>", "40");<?php

                        }
                        if(count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) > 2 && count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) <= 4) {
                            ?> localStorage.setItem("progressLevel" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['level'] ?>", "30");<?php

                        }
                        if(count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) > 4 && count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) <= 6) {
                            ?> localStorage.setItem("progressLevel" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['level'] ?>", "20");<?php

                        }
                        if(count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) > 6 && count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) <= 8) {
                            ?> localStorage.setItem("progressLevel" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['level'] ?>", "10");<?php

                        }
                        if(count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) > 8 && count($_SESSION['seenWrong']) <= 10) {
                            ?> localStorage.setItem("progressLevel" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['level'] ?>", "0");<?php
                        }
                        unset($_SESSION['level']);
                        unset($_SESSION['id']);
                        $_SESSION['seenRight'] = array();
                        $_SESSION['seenWrong'] = array();
                        header('Location:review_menu.php'); // IF THIS IS REMOVED, IT WORKS FINE.
                    ?>
            } else {
                <?php header('Location:review_menu.php'); ?>
            }
        </script> <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> placing the header to a different page

...you said it yourself. You tell the browser to go to another page...so this page, the one you're outputting the localstorage code into, never gets loaded by the browser and so of course the JavaScript never executes.

If you want to do a redirect, I suggest doing it from javascript (e.g. using `window.location`), after the localstorage code has had chance to execute.

Comment: They're sending the header after outputting HTML, so shouldn't they get a `Header already sent` failure?

Comment: @Barmar good point actually.  Perhaps OP would care to give a clearer description of what they're actually seeing

Comment: It seemed to work fine now with the solution from @ADyson. I'm quite new to programming in general so I'm still unsure why window.location works and header doesn't. What previously was happening was that if placed the header to 'review_menu.php'. I'd be sent to that page but the localStorage value wouldn't be updated. When I removed the header and went manually to 'review_menu.php' the localStorage value was updated. Overall I got no error messages either on screen or in the console, just wasn't working as I expected it to. Now it seems to be working fine. Thanks guys!

Comment: @luan_navarro glad you've fixed it but a but surprised you're still confused, as I thought I'd explained why it happens. If you set a redirect header on the php side then the browser will immediately redirects without loading the page at all, therefore the javascript cannot run (since that is executed by the browser). Is there anything in that scenario you're not quite clear about?